# What is the origin of the word "washel"?

Tags: etymology

My wife's family uses the word "washel"or "washle". They are from eastern Ohio, in and about Mineral Ridge, Ohio.

They use it in place of *crumple*,  as in "washel a piece of paper".  Not sure of spelling, sounds like *mash*.

Anyone know the origin?

Comment: Do you have any evidence that anyone *apart from your wife's family* uses this word? And it might help to know where they came from, obviously. Might it be a corruption of ***ruffle, wrinkle, rumple,*** or similar? There's also ***warsle***, which I didn't know before now (Scottish / Northern English dialectal derivative of ***wrestle***, apparently), that *might* be used in this way.

Comment: This might be dialectal, so it would be good to know where your wife's family is from.

Comment: eastern Ohio, in and about Mineral Ridge, Ohio

Comment: JBW: if you haven’t gotten an answer to this in a couple days, ping me (like “pinging @DanBron”), and I’ll pay for a bounty on it (don’t worry, it won’t cost me any actual money, just imaginary internet points, and I have stacks of the stuff lying around doing nothing).

Comment: I checked my dead-tree edition of DARE (the Dictionary of American Regional English) but was unable to find this word using any spelling variant (like "we-" , "wha-", etc.) I could think of.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure on the origin of the word, but I can contribute that it doesn't seem to be dialectal or unique to your family.

[Google's Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=washel&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=50&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwashel%3B%2Cc0) shows that it's been around at least since 1800, and was actually in greater use then.

[The University of Michigan seems to treat it as a noun.](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=id&id=MED51840)

[Page 393](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=wV_PYoiC67MC&pg=PA393&lpg=PA393&dq=define%20washel&source=bl&ots=nGNrURv8WX&sig=dCzt7LSxeXPmmzqE3XAPfTAVrAQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjs99ObgO7eAhWSV30KHaKSBzk4ChDoATADegQICRAB#v=onepage&q&f=false) of Robert E Lewis' *Middle English Dictionary* seems to indicate *washel* is only a noun, equivalent to *vessel* and originating from *weshel*.

Under the heading *Old Edinburgh*, David Maxwell's *Bygone Scotland* [seems to support the use of *weshel* in this sense](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/54245/54245-0.txt) - "*within covered weshel*".
[Page 83](https://deriv.nls.uk/dcn23/1271/7973/127179731.23.pdf) of *Seafield Correspondence 1685-1708* also seems to use the word this way - 'especially the weshell that is not come up as yet' ("espeallie the weshell that is not come vp as yet").

These sources seem to indicate that although *washel* is not unique to your family, the meaning your family uses it with is unique. As such, the origin could only be guessed at - perhaps a spelling mistake, or someone mishearing someone else. I would ask the family if they knew its origin.

Comment: That's not the same word—the OP's word is a verb. It's like the difference between *pear* and *pare*, which also aren't the same word.

Comment: Looking at some instances of "washel" linked from Ngram Viewer, they seem to be OCR artifacts: the actual images invariably show the word to be "washed".

Comment: _That's not the same word_ is exactly what I'm saying - Google's Ngram Viewer indicates that the word 'washel' has been around for quite some time, but the Ngram doesn't take into account which part of speech it is, so I compared OP's with other people's usage to demonstrate that his family's use is unique in that it is a verb, and has a different meaning to traditional usage (where washel comes from weshel meaning vessel).

Because it is a different word, I suggest that OP's is unique to his family.